# AudioContext and animation do not work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile, audiocontext

I have this little code snippet here

```
var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
.....
var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
analyser.fftSize = 256;

var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;

var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height + (canvas.height * 0.7);

var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
var barHeight;
var x = 0;


function renderFrame() {
  x = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

  for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
    barHeight = dataArray[i];
    var r = barHeight + (25 * (i / bufferLength));
    var g = 250 * (i / bufferLength);
    var b = 50;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
    x += barWidth + 1;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
}
requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);


audio.src = jQuery("source").attr("src");
audio.play();
```

Full code and demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/6gv39mk0/1/show

That basically shows a dynamic waveform when audio is played

[image]

It works on desktop browser, android browser, but no way to make it works on iPhone. Am I missing something or is there something that I must declare/do differently?

Comment: Does it work on safari on the desktop? Safari has some pretty tough default settings when it comes to automatically playing audio via javascript.  My guess would be that if you take a look at the console of the mobile browser you'll see that webkit is complaining about auto playing audio, and there's really not much to get around it.  The user needs to set a preference to allow auto playing audio on web pages.

Comment: Hello @DaveVanFleet. On Safari Desktop it plays but without animation. Unfortunately, I do not have an iPhone to verify console or error logs. Anyway, it should not be related to the auto-play, because I'm still using the play button of the audio player, so the end user must still click on that button.

Comment: I've solved it. Added a transparent button on play button make the trick. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L1trwz7o/

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue with a transparent button on top of play button. this probably make iPhone browsers understand that there is an interaction. After that the button is hidden (z-index -1)
It's not that elegant as solution, but it work!

```
  var button = document.createElement('button');
    jQuery(button).attr('id', 'btn');
    jQuery(canva).before(button);
    jQuery(button).on('click', function() {
        start();
      jQuery(button).remove();
    })
```

here it is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L1trwz7o/